# how to compare total in unix

Tags: bash, shell, grep

i have a file simple.txt. with contents as below:

```
a b 
c d
c d
```

I want to check which pair 'a b' or 'c d' has maximum occurrence? I have written this code which gives me output of individual occurrence of each word :

```
cat simple.txt | tr -cs '[:alnum:]' '[\n*]' | sort | uniq -c | 
grep -E -i  "\<a\>|\<b\>|\<c\>|\<d\>"

1 a
1 b
2 c
2 d
```

how can i total the result of this output? or can i write a different code?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Pipe it to `wc` or `paste -sd+ | bc`

Comment: expected output is "the pair with max occurence is:ab (or cd)"

Answer (score 1):

If we can assume that each pair of letters is a complete line, one way to handle this would be to **sort** the lines, use the **uniq** utility to get a count of each unique line, and then reverse **sort** to get the count:

```
sort simple.txt | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

You may want to get rid of the empty lines using **egrep**:

```
egrep '\w' simple.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

Which should give you:

```
2 c d
1 a b
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the pair that occurs most frequently:

```
$ sort <simple.txt | uniq -c | sort -nr | awk '{print "The pair with max occurence is",$2,$3; exit}'
The pair with max occurence is c d
```

This can be done entirely by awk and without any need for pipelines:

```
$ awk '{a[$0]++} END{for (x in a) if (a[x]>(max+0)) {max=a[x]; line=x}; print "The pair with max occurence is",line}' simple.txt
The pair with max occurence is c d
```

Comment: you have to sort numerically, otherwise lexicographical order `10 < 2`

Comment: @karakfa Good point!  Thanks.  Answer updated so that the second `sort` sorts numerically.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sort file | 
  uniq -c   | 
  sort -nr > >(read -r count pair; echo "max count $count is for pair $pair")
```

sort, count numerically in descending order, read the first and print the results.

or all the above in one `awk` script...

```
$ awk '{c[$0]++} 
    END{n=asorti(c,ci); k=ci[n]; 
        print "max count is " c[k] " for pair " k}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With single GNU **`awk`** command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc" }
     NF{ a[$0]++ }
     END{ for (i in a) { print "The pair with max occurence is:", i; break } }' file
```

The output:

```
The pair with max occurence is: c d
```